# Compare and then output value based on array key

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am having a hard time figuring this out.

Background:

I am outputting various image sizes for different screens via graphQL and then mapping them:

```
const variantSizes = variants.map(el => ({
          320: el.node.defaultImage.url_320,
          640: el.node.defaultImage.url_640,
          768: el.node.defaultImage.url_768,
          1280: el.node.defaultImage.url_1280,
          1920: el.node.defaultImage.url_1920,
          2560: el.node.defaultImage.url_2560
        }));
```

Which outputs me this:

[image: console output]

Then I set my different screen sizes and I am checking the container width and based on the closest value it outputs me the value which should be displayed:

```
        const imageContainer = document.querySelector("#splide-slide01");
        const containerWidth = imageContainer.offsetWidth;

        const counts = [320, 640, 768, 960, 1280, 1920, 2560];
        const goal = containerWidth;

        const output = counts.reduce((prev, curr) => Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
```

And now is the part where I am struggling.

I am trying to compare these two, so the array key and the **const output** and if they match, so if the key name of the **VariantSizes** match, it should output me the value of that key.

But I have no idea how to take the name of the value, not the value itself of these mapped **VariantSizes** and then compare that to the **output** of the screensize and then output the value of the matched one.

So basically what I am trying to achieve:

User with screensize close to 640px goes on the site, it will match that to the 640px value based on the **const reduce** and this value will then be matched to the **640** name from the **const variantSizes** and it will output the value of that 640 form the variantSizes.

That value is basically the image URL for that particular size, which then I will take and put into the src of the main image.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your first code block/console output doesnt make sense. `map` will give you an array but it looks like a single object in your output. In any case, assuming `variantSizes` is an object you just need square bracket notation `const img = variantSizes[output]` - if `output` was `640` you'll get `variantSizes[640]`

Comment: I feel stupid now, this is literally it. Spend some time building it and the last step got me confused. Needed another pair of eyes to take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully clear what you want to achieve, sorry. But I'll try to help.

Variant sizes looks like an array, but your console output shows the object.
So there is two ways of solving this.

If you have an object you can just go for:

```js
const resultImage = variantSizes[output]
```

If you have an array of objects and need to get array of strings you can go for:

```js
const resultImages = variantSizes.map(variant => variant[output])
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it! I feel kind of stupid now, because this is really simple. Probably needed another pair of eyes to take a look since I spend some time already thinking about this.